# Pass Context Data to Django Template from View

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am sure there is something simple I am missing.  I am trying to pass context from my view to the the template and can't seem to get it to work.  I know I could simply type into the template but there are other things I need to do and getting this will get me part way there.  Thank you.

**View**

```
class ProductView(ListView):
    model = Section
    template_name = 'products/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['title'] = 'San Diego'
        return context_data
```

**Template**

```
...
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
...
```

Comment: That's weird. Show your `urls.py` please. Also the template you're showing is `products/home.html`, right?

Comment: sorry, I am an idiot...I was looking at the live site and not local...it works as expected.

Comment: Your question answered my question